# Using the definite article with comparative adjectives

Tags: grammaticality

> It appears that **the stronger** argument is in favour of grandparents living independently.

We normally use **the** with superlative adjectives. Here **the** is used before **stronger** as a comparative adjective; making me confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the definite article chooses someone/thing that is **specific.** Say,

> Two boxers are fighting. **The stronger** one wins.

Here, the article picks one from those two.

However, you are right that the definite article is common with superlative degrees.

Answer (score 6):

If the sentence read:

> It appears that the **strongest** argument is...

that would mean that there are at least three arguments.

However, since it reads:

> It appears that the **stronger** argument is...

that seems to imply we are talking about two opposing stances on an issue.

Either way, when we refer to just one of those multiple arguments, we can use the definite article:

- It appears the weaker argument is...
- It appears the most foolish argument is...
- It appears the less sensible argument is...
- It appears the easier option would be...

and so forth.

Comment: There is no reason why "the strongest" can't apply to two.

Comment: @Paul Childs: Indeed. Doubtless the vast majority of contexts for [*may the **best** man win*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=may+the+better+man+win%2Cmay+the+best+man+win&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmay%20the%20better%20man%20win%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmay%20the%20best%20man%20win%3B%2Cc0) involve just ***two*** contenders. But I'm sure most instances of the sequence *two children the **eldest / elder*** would be for the construction under consideration here, and charting *those* strongly supports J.R.'s assertion re the ***norm***.

Comment: @PaulC - Good point. Some pedantic grammarians might disagree with you, but I won't.